# Transmit at the 300 MHZ - 400 MHZ range

Tags: radio-firmware

Is there any piece of hardware in a modern Android phone (Galaxy S5+) that can transmit at the 300-400 MHZ range?

If so does this require cracking the radio ROM or is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A typical device (such as the S5) lacks the hardware support for your frequencies of interest.  However, there are some specialty devices such as the Runbo X6 (http://www.runboeurope.com/runbo-x6/) which support UHF communications now, with VHF planned.

If you were to add the appropriate hardware to an S5 as an accessory, the easiest way to interact with it would be from userspace (e.g., via an app or service), not by messing with the radio ROM.